# How to test exception with JUnit 5 if assertThrows is not catching the exception (Kotlin)

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, junit5

I am writing a test explanation, of which I have done this plenty of times, and I am getting strange behavior. I run the test and then I get:

```
No username
com.bsb.pr.test.domain.UserException: No username
    at app//com.bsb.pr.test.service.UserService.fetchUserById(UserService.kt:21)
    at app//com.bsb.pr.test.UserServiceTestNoKSpock.getUserNameById throws exception if username is null(UserServiceTestNoKSpock.kt:23)
    at java.base@17.0.4/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
```

The follow is the code that is used:

```
@Service
class SubscriptionService {

    fun getSubscriptionByUserId(id: Number): Subscription? {
        return Subscription("email@email.com")
    }
}
```

```
@Service
class UsernameService {
    fun getUserNameById(id: Number): Username? = Username("test")
}
```

**Focal Service**

```
@Service
class UserService(
    private val usernameService: UsernameService,
    private val subscriptionService: SubscriptionService
) {

    fun fetchUserById(id: Number): User {
        val username: Username =
            usernameService
                .getUserNameById(id)
                ?: throw UserException("No username")

        val subscription: Subscription =
            subscriptionService
                .getSubscriptionByUserId(id)
                ?: throw UserException("No subscription")

        return User(id, username.content, subscription)
    }
}
```

**Focal test**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.assertThrows
import org.mockito.Mockito


class UserServiceTest {
    private val usernameService: UsernameService = Mockito.mock(UsernameService::class.java)
    private val subscriptionService: SubscriptionService = Mockito.mock(SubscriptionService::class.java)

    private val userService = UserService(usernameService, subscriptionService)

    @Test
    fun `getUserNameById throws exception if username is null`() {
        // setup mocks
        Mockito.`when`(userService.fetchUserById(1)).thenReturn(null)

        // whenever
        val userException: UserException = assertThrows { userService.fetchUserById(1) }

        assert(userException.message == "No username")

        Mockito.verify(userService).fetchUserById(1)
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.15.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

I have tried different forms of that assertThrows and looked at other online documentation.

It should notice the exception and then pass.

Comment: I have even tried wrapping it in a try catch in the test and it fails. I tried changing my custom exception to Throwable, just generic Exception, kotlins flavor of Mockito, etc  and it is the same result

Comment: I remade the test in a separate location and it works...

Still stands to figure out why it would not work.

The original test location:
`test/com/bsb/pr/test/UserServiceTest`

The new test location:
`test/com/bsb/pr/test/remake/UserServiceTest`

Usually I would put that test under the `service` folder but I was just doing a quick tutorial and figured exact location didn't matter.